# How to set recipients with Gmail's Node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail-api

As simple as it may seem, I cannot seem to figure out how to set recipients of a draft with Google's Gmail API. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) says that a `users.messages Resource` object contains a `payload` object that contains a `headers` object, and that `headers` object contains name-value pairs.

```
// example from google's gmail API documentation
"payload": {
  "partId": string,
  "mimeType": string,
  "filename": string,
  "headers": [
    {
      "name": string,
      "value": string
    }
  ],
  "body": users.messages.attachments Resource,
  "parts": [
    (MessagePart)
  ]
},
```

It is within these headers I presume you set the "To" part of a draft, since the documentation says

> List of headers on this message part. For the top-level message part, representing the entire message payload, it will contain the standard RFC 2822 email headers such as To, From, and Subject.

however, when I make a request that looks something like this

```
"payload" : {
  "headers" : [
    {
      "name"  : "To",
      "value" : "me"
      // "me" should direct the draft to myself
    }
  ]
}
```

the To part of the draft is still left empty. Any solution or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it appears that I was misinterpreting documentation on the Gmail API. When you send a request to drafts.create, you do need to supply is a `users.messages Resource`, however, not all of it is writable. Only `threadId`, `labelIds`, and `raw` are writable objects. As it turns out, you aren't supposed to use the payload at all to set the `To`, `From`, etc. You are supposed to include them in your raw.

My new code looks something like this

```
let create = (toAddress, subject, content, callback) => {
  gmail.users.drafts.create(
    {
      'userId'  : 'me',
      'resource' : {
        'message' : {
          'raw' : base64.encodeURI(
                    `To:${toAddress}\r\n` + // Who were are sending to
                    `Subject:${subject}\r\n` + // Subject
                    `Date:\r\n` + // Removing timestamp
                    `Message-Id:\r\n` + // Removing message id
                    `From:\r\n` + // Removing from
                    `${content}` // Adding our actual message
                  )
        }
      }
    },
    (err, response) => {
      // Do stuff with response
      callback(err, response);
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your request you have this:

`"headers" : [ "name" : "To", "value" : "me" ]`

`"headers"` is supposed to be an array of objects but your array contains none.

Instead, it should look like this:

`"headers": [ { "name": "To", "value": "me" } ]`

Just like their example:

```
"payload": {
  "partId": string,
  "mimeType": string,
  "filename": string,
  "headers": [
    {
      "name": "To",
      "value": "me"
    }
  ],
  "body": users.messages.attachments Resource,
  "parts": [
    (MessagePart)
  ]
},
```

Comment: Woops, that was actually a typo. I am writing in my local code that way, but same results when I attempt to create a draft.